# How to render row image date without using send_data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gruff

I am using gruff to create an image. I have created an image and now I have a raw image data.
I don't want to use `gruff.write('image.png')` as I want the application to be fast. I want t be able to display that raw image data on the view.

But the problem is in this: I **can't use controllers** - so `send_data` is out of the picture, I guess.
Is there a way to use raw image data that I have in my Helper method, and use that helper method to display the image in the view?

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def generated_image()
    @graph = create_gruff("50x50", "%m/%d") do |g|
      #some code to create a graph
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You could base64 encode the data and put it in a variable, then render the variable value, for example: <img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= @raw_base_64" %> />

Comment: Hm, interesting, I might give it a try. In the mean time I have created a new controller, created new custom path e.g. /generated_image.jpg and I am re-referencing in my template like `<img src="myapp.com/generated_image.jpg" />` But I will check further and check your suggestion also. Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have one answer on this question, and I am putting it as an answer:

I have created a new controller, created new custom `path` e.g. `/generated_image.jpg` and I am re-referencing in my template like

That is how I can render a raw image. There are other options, but for the case I needed this is the option I used.